# hotwords demo segfaults on VM running bionic

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

Im trying to get the Assistant Python library demos running. I download my client credentials file, run the auth/consent tool as follows:
(env) $ google-oauthlib-tool --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype       --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gcm       --save --headless --client-secrets client_secret_XXXXX.json

The tool shows a URL that I visit and click through - the subsequent web shows me an auth string that I copy and paste back into the waiting terminal session.
(the tool tells me that it updated a .config/ file)

OK I then run...
(env) $ googlesamples-assistant-hotword --project-id ${project} --device-model-id ${model-id}

which results in a segfault:
device_model_id: dawnstar-226520-dawnstar-test-rig-jcsgzj
device_id: 4BAE41228DA8890AB0DDE6FD6992F5BF

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
(env) $

I have confirmed the project ID, model ID and that the Assistant API is enabled

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to a change from Google Assistant Library to Google Assistant Service. The Google Assistant Library is deprecated.

As shown in this [project page issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/313), the issue affect to the components still based on Google Assistant Library, like googlesamples-assistant-hotword.

Other resources, like googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk now are working over gRPC and this is the new way to use this service.

There is also a working task to [improve](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/356) the system over gRPC.